# python3 - printing a file I just wrote to

Tags: python, python-3.x

this is a question from one of the exercises in learn python the hard way.  The exercise was to copy one file to another, which I have working fine, but I want to extend the code a bit to print the file a just wrote to.  Here is the code:

```
from sys import argv
from os.path import exists

script, from_file, to_file = argv

print(f"Copying from {from_file} to {to_file}")

#creates a variable called "in_file" from the argv "from_file", opens it and reads it.
in_file = open(from_file).read()
print(f"The contents of 'from_file' is:\n {in_file}")

print(f"The input file is {len(in_file)} bytes long")
print(f"Does the output file exist? {exists(to_file)}")
print(f"Ready, hit RETURN to contiune, CTRC-C to abort")
input(">")

#creates variable "out_file" and opens the "to file" argv 'w' means writable
out_file = open(to_file, 'w')

#writes data from "in_file to "out_file"
out_file.write(in_file)

print("Alright, all done")

#Try to print the file we wrote to
blah = open(to_file).read()
print(f"We printed: {blah}")
```

When I run this script this is what happens:

```
$ python3 ex17.py test.text new_file.text
Copying from test.text to new_file.text
The contents of 'from_file' is:
 This is a test file.

The input file is 21 bytes long
Does the output file exist? True
Ready, hit RETURN to contiune, CTRC-C to abort
>
Alright, all done
We printed:
```

So my issues is that nothing is printing out.  if I cat the "new_file.text" the contents is correct but something is obviously wrong with the code since it's not printing it at all.

Any suggestions?

Comment: use with context blocks or `out_file.close()` ...

Comment: close files that you open. ideally, dont open without a `with` statement. You're making an assumption that the moment the `.write` is executed, the contents have been written to the file. This assumption, surprisingly, can fail.

Comment: ohhhhh thank you!! i thought the file was closed automatically once the write operation was completed.  This solved it, thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested it. This is because out_file is not closed. After adding `out_file.close()` to `out_file.write(in_file)`, of course, it is recommended that you use `with` instead of opening the file.